# Bluetooth audio skipping while wifi active

Tags: wireless, sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio

I've a bluetooth speaker and got it to work. But audio is terrible, skips lots of times:

```
Aug 28 21:02:25 test pulseaudio[2537]: [bluetooth] module-bluez5-device.c: Skipping 309976 us (= 54676 bytes) in audio stream
Aug 28 21:02:25 test pulseaudio[2537]: [bluetooth] module-bluez5-device.c: Skipping 84982 us (= 14988 bytes) in audio stream
Aug 28 21:02:26 test pulseaudio[2537]: [bluetooth] module-bluez5-device.c: Skipping 208448 us (= 36768 bytes) in audio stream
```

Since the wifi and BT come altogether, thought on turning off the wifi connection for a while: **bingo! with wifi disabled BT audio sounds perfect.**

```
lucas@test:~$ sudo lshw -c Network 
  *-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
   logical name: wlo1
   version: 01
   serial: d8:5d:e2:cc:38:5d
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) ip=192.168.0.2 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:18 memory:b5500000-b5507fff

lucas@test:~$ sudo lsusb -v | grep Blue
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0a5c:216c Broadcom Corp. BCM43142A0 Bluetooth    Device
  idProduct          0x216c BCM43142A0 Bluetooth Device
```

I'm using:

```
lucas@test:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

lucas@test:~$ uname -a
Linux test 4.10.0-32-generic #36~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 9 09:19:02 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Is there any possible way of having both BT+wifi active without getting this choppy audio? Might it be due to channel interference?

thanks!

Comment: This bug is what you should be looking for https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/405294